# ListView with Label and a database binding

Tags: xaml

I want to implement a `Listview` to have 3 database fields on one row: First Name, Middle Initial, and Last Name:

```
<Label Text="{Binding FName}" />
<Label Text="{Binding MName}" />
<Label Text="{Binding LName}" />
```

Is there a way to get nice formatting? Is `StackPanel` the only option? This is inside a list view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ListView ItemTemplate for that, you can also use a `Grid` to align the labels.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FName}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MName}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```